# How to resolve "Cannot connect to AppleID server" error on macOS?

Tags: macos, apple-id

This is a problem that is getting bigger and bigger for me.

My Apple ID works perfectly on my iPad and iPhone. I can change the password etc and it all works fine. On my computer however it continues to give me the message (Cannot connect to APPLE ID SERVER).This means I can't backup to icloud or do any updates etc. I feel like I have tried everything imaginable to get this to work including talking to APPLE SUPPORT on the phone. WIFI connections all fine. This has been a problem I have had for quite a while.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: First: Check on https://appleid.apple.com/ with Safari wether you can login with your Apple ID. Which MacOS version are you using?

Comment: Thank you :) So my ipad is 12.5.2 - It says that I have no updates even though this isn't the latest version. I can't update it by using my computer because my itunes is now 'Music' and I can't use my apple ID to change it to itunes. I've tried downloading itunes but it says no versions are compatible with Big Sur 11.2.3 when I try to download it.

Comment: I checked using the appleid.apple.com and yes I can sign into that. It works perfectly.

Comment: Did you install a VPN in the past? Or are you blocking [any relevant port](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944) in the [firewall](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh34041/mac)?

Comment: I've removed the numbers/excel part, please ask a new question for this if necessary.

Comment: Could you include a screen shot of the actual error message you’re seeing?

Comment: You mention your iPad being on 12.5.2, but the problem here is about your Mac. So which version of macOS are you actually running? Where/in which application are you trying to log in with your AppleID and get the error mentioned?

Comment: It say's 'Verification Failed' There was an error connecting to the Apple ID Server. (Sorry I can't see how to attach the photo. Also Usually it just says 'There was an error connecting to the Apple ID Server'. I am currently running on my MAC - 11.2.3 - BIG SUR

Comment: I have also checked to see if there is a VPN on my computer and it doesn't look like there is. I have used VPN's in the past but I can't remember if that was this computer or not?? I also turned the firewall off then the computer and tried apple id again but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you think changing my Apple ID username and password would allow me in?

Comment: Screenshots can be added by editing the question and clicking on the image icon next to {} in the bar above the edit box.

Answer (score 0):

So if you can log into your Apple ID from a browser an incorrect time zone settings might cause an error in connecting your Apple ID with the Store.
To correct your time and date settings, go to Settings > General > Date & Time and make sure that everything is set correctly.

Now: Open iTunes
Click on iTunes in the Menu Bar.
Select Preferences.

[image]

Go to the Advanced Tab.
Click the Reset Cache button.
Click OK.
Close and re-open iTunes.
Now, try to sign in to the iTunes store.

Comment: Thanks. I did this but still no effect. So when I try to sign in to apple id on my mac it still says....cannot connect to apple id server :(

Comment: Also I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it but SAFARI is basically unusable too. I mainly use chrome